# Google Colaboratoryでツールバーが表示されなくなりました。

Tags: google-colaboratory

Google Colaboratoryを使用しているのですが、ファイル、編集などのツールバーが表示されなくなりました。設定を見てもツールバーを表示するような項目が見当たりません。Colaboratoryをアンインストールして再度インストールしてみたのですが状況に変化はありません。どなたかツールバーを表示する方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: Google Colab はブラウザ上で使用するツールかと思います。画面イメージなども含めておくと回答が付きやすいかもしれません。

Comment: colabの右上が「v」のような表示なら押すとヘッダー表示されます

Comment: oririさん、ご呈示の方法で解決いたしました。画面をくまなく見たつもりでしたが見落としていました。ありがとうございました。